# how to fetch unique categories from products collection based on brand in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have 3 collection in firebase

1. Brands
   (BrandId as String, Title as String)
2. Categories
   (CategoryId as String, Title as String)
3. Products.
   (ProductId as String, Title as String, CategoryId as String, BrandId as String IsFeautured as bool)

Here are products data which i have uploaded to Products Collection

```
 
 static List<ProductModel> products=[

    //samsung brands
    ProductModel(productId: '01', title: 'Galaxy Book1', brandId: '1', categoryId: '2', isFeautured: true),
    ProductModel(productId: '02', title: 'Galaxy Book2', brandId: '1', categoryId: '2', isFeautured: true),

    ProductModel(productId: '03', title: 'S21 Ultra', brandId: '1', categoryId: '1', isFeautured: true),

    ProductModel(productId: '07', title: 'S3 Gear Watch', brandId: '1', categoryId: '3', isFeautured: true),]
```

and here are brand & Category data which are uploaded to collection named Brands and Categories

```
static  List<BrandModel> brands=[
    BrandModel(brandId: '1', title: 'Samsung', isFeautured: true),
    BrandModel(brandId: '2', title: 'Apple', isFeautured: true),
    BrandModel(brandId: '3', title: 'Nokia', isFeautured: true),
  ];


 static List<CategoryModel> cateogories=[
    CategoryModel(categoryId: '1', title: 'Mobile', isFeautured: true),
    CategoryModel(categoryId: '2', title: 'Laptop', isFeautured: true),
    CategoryModel(categoryId: '3', title: 'Watch', isFeautured: true),
    CategoryModel(categoryId: '4', title: 'Sounds', isFeautured: true),
  ];
```

My query is that I have created a screen of all brands...tapping on any brand its moving to next screen where its shows all available category of this brand having products..

Like if i tap on Samsung, samsung screen should show three kind of category Mobile, Laptop and watch

so how to get this..I have tried following but dont know how to implement for category

```
Future<List<CategoryModel>> fetchAvailableCategoryOfBrand(String brandId) async{
    List<CategoryModel> uniqueCategories = [];
    final _db=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final list=await _db.collection("Products").where('BrandId',isEqualTo: brandId).get();
    

//this is fetching given brand data..but how to fetch unique category of from it
/// what code for fetching unique categories and what if products are in thousands...

    return uniqueCategories;
  }
```

Comment: I was advised to do..first fetch all products to an array than filter with brand and than add unique category inside an array and return...but i think this is not good approach...traversing to all products is not advisable i think..guessing i have lakhs products

Comment: i'm missing the connection between brand and category in the datamodel. It would be easier to fetch the data when you have in brand, a array with category ids

Comment: but you already fetch all product for the brand then get the product category ids and fetch all categories from the products categories

Comment: guessing i have thousands products and than a loop for finding unique categories...is that right approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think your current approach has a lot more reads than necessary. In your example, if you tap Samsung, you query the products collection to get all Samsung products and then display the categories that Samsung has. That might be fine for now, but if you have a lot of products, that won't scale nicely.

Having only 2 collection might be a lot more scalable.
Keep products the same, and add a property to your brand docs called 'categories' this could then be an array of the category ids. Also add this as a property of your brand object.

This would allow for a few things. At app launch, all the brands are read and stored as brand objects. Lets say you have 20 brands, that's 20 reads. If you tap Samsung, there is no need for addition reads, you simply display the categories that the brand object says it has. When a specific category is tapped, then you fetch from the products collection.

```dart
final list = await _db.collection("Products")
.where('BrandId',isEqualTo: brandId)
.where('CategoryId', isEqualTo: categoryId)
.get();
```

Lets continue with the Samsung example. Lets say they have 100 mobile products, and 2 laptop products. If you read for all products as soon as the brand is tapped, and then the user taps laptops, all 100 mobile reads were for nothing. Again, doesn't seem like a lot not, but that will not scale.

There isn't really any low-read way to determine all the unique categories of a brand from reading the products collection. The only way to do it would be to read all of them and pull the uniques like you had mentioned in your comment.

With the above solution of having 2 collections, you can also have a button on the category selection screen to 'show all'. You can also add pagination to the brand or product lists to further reduce reads.

Not sure how products are added to the products collection, but lets say a new product is added to the Samsung collection. When adding a new product, you an check to see if that products category id already exists within the Samsung doc, if it does, don't update it, just add the new product. If it doesn't, that means it's the first product of that category for Samsung, and you can add that collection id to the Samsung doc.

Comment: Thanks for your very brief answer.... This is what i wanted to know..and will improve my code and let you know if i got any other solution...Thanks again..